# AWS GREENGRASS Cannot connect to device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot-greengrass

I am new to AWS IoT. Can you please guide me or refer me some helpful material to implement whole greengrass. I want to use raspberry pi as my greengrass core in gg group and I want to establish communication between different devices which in my case are esp8266 and esp32 through raspberry pi.

Instead of terminal in my computer I want to use one esp8266 as publisher and another esp8266 as subscriber and exchange data between them via raspberry pi (greengrass core). I have no idea if I have to install device SDK on esp or what? I am finding no way out from here.

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: [Had you looked at here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-greengrass-developer-guide/tree/master/doc_source)

Answer (score 1):

First you should read about Greengrass which you can find useful information and how to install it on RaspberryPi [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html).
Then you should choose which kinds of OS you want to use for your ESPs. You can use:

- Amazon FreeRTOS
- MongooseOS
- Zerynth

I recommend to use Amazon FreeRTOS because it is well-known and the documentations are very good. You can find more information to get started with it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/freertos-getting-started.html). You should consider that all of your devices (RaspberryPi and ESPs) should be in the same network and you should set the IP of the broker in your ESPs to the IP of your RaspberryPi in your local network. Also you should set the devices to be in same group in AWS IoT console and deploy the configuration to the Greengrass. The policies for IoT devices should allow them to publish/subscribe. For connecting to the AWS broker all of devices should have valid certifications and for connecting ESPs to the Greengrass network CA root certificate should be replaced by Greengrass group certificate.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use esp8266 with aws Greengrass, because esp8266 doesn't support TLS 1.2 communication and aws IoT required TLS 1.2.

You can use esp32, which support TLS 1.2 and can exchange certificate, and establish the secure connection with aws greengrass.

I have written an [article](https://medium.com/@shehrazjazib/aws-iot-and-greengrass-using-espressif-esp32-devkitc-with-zerynth-studio-db88b8028b85), which explain each and every steps, how you can start from stracth to advance level.

[Zerynth](https://www.zerynth.com/) official has featured this article on their [blog](https://www.zerynth.com/blog/new-tutorial-on-medium-about-using-zerynth-with-aws/). So follow it and complete your solution.